# Triggering a route only after dispatch and commit completed in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, es6-promise, vue-router, vuex

I do have a form submit which takes email and password then pass them into an action in store called `userSignIn`

*SignIn.vue :*

```
onSubmit () {
    if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
    const user = {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
    }
    this.$store.dispatch('userSignIn', user)
        .then(() => {
            this.$router.push('/')
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
}
```

Within store, I do have a `userSignIn` action like this

*store.js actions:*

```
userSignIn ({commit, getters}, payload) {
    getters.Api.post(`user/signin`, {
        email: payload.email,
        password: payload.password
    }).then(res => {
        commit('userSignIn', res.data.token)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

The routing(`this.$router.push('/')`) should only be done after `userSignIn` commit(`commit('userSignIn', res.data.token)`). But what actually happening routing triggers before commit, which results and error because user token is not set yet.

**How to trigger something(in this case `this.$router.push('/')`) only after completion of `dispatch` and `commit` within it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning the promise did the trick.

```
userSignIn ({commit, getters}, payload) {
    return getters.Api.post(`user/signin`, {
        ......
    })
```