# Vuex store/navigation guard doesn't work first time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have a navigation guard on a user's dashboard which requires a user to exist to proceed.

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      name: 'dashboard',
      component: Dashboard,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        const user = JSON.parse(store.state.authenticatedUser)
        if(user) {
          console.log("Route accepted.")
          next()
        } else {
          console.log("Route rejected.")
          next('/')
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

On my login form, I dispatch to obtainToken which returns the token and associated user.

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <h1 class="display-2">Login</h1>
    <v-form 
      ref="form" 
      v-model="valid" 
      lazy-validation
    >
      <v-col cols="12" md="12">
        <v-row align="center">
          <v-text-field 
            v-model="email" 
            :rules=emailRules 
            label="Email" 
            required 
            dense
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-row>
        <v-row align="center">
          <v-text-field 
            v-model="password"
            label="Password"
            required
            dense
            type="password"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-row>
      </v-col>
      <v-btn
        @click="login"
      >Login</v-btn>
    </v-form>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    valid: true,
    password: '',
    email: '',
    emailRules: [
      v => !!v || 'Email is required.',
      v => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || 'You have entered an invalid email.',
    ],
  }),
  methods: {
    login() {
      this.$store.dispatch('obtainToken', { email: this.email, password: this.password })
      this.$router.push('dashboard')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```
  actions: {
    logout() {
      this.commit('revokeUser')
      this.commit('revokeToken')
    },
    obtainToken(random, payload) {
      const data = {
        email: payload.email,
        password: payload.password
      }

      api.post(this.state.endpoints.obtainToken, data)
      .then((response => {
        this.commit('updateSessionUser', response.data.user)
        this.commit('updateToken', response.data.token)
      }))
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
      })
    },
```

When clicking `submit`, the user is obtained, but the route is rejected because at the time a user doesn't exist. I have to click `submit` a second time which will allow the user to access the `dashboard` route.

[image]

So what I can gather from the output is that the `$router.push` is occurring as `obtainToken` is occurring so they race. Logging in a second time there is already a user present, so it proceeds. What am I doing wrong here?

---

I have as well tried to make it so router.push() is called as resolution to the promise as well.

```
login() {
      this.$store.dispatch('obtainToken', { email: this.email, password: this.password })
      .then(() =>
           this.$router.push('dashboard')
      )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `dispatch` is async.

When changing the router, it is undefined yet.

So you need to call dispatch in `mounted()` before to move another page.

```
mounted() {
  this.$store.dispatch('obtainToken', { email: this.email, password: this.password })
},
methods: {
  login() {
    this.$router.push('dashboard')
  }
}
```

Or

```
methods: {
  login() {
    this.$store.dispatch('obtainToken', { email: this.email, password: this.password }).then(() => this.$router.push('dashboard'))
  }
}
```

EDIT: You need to return `promise` in `obtainToken` like below;

```
obtainToken(random, payload) {
  ...
  return api.post(this.state.endpoints.obtainToken, data) // just add `return`
  ...
}
```

Comment: This would mean that I'm calling obtainToken as the login form is mounted, which would result in unnecessary api calls. Email and password don't exist until user provides them and obtainToken should only be called when user adds them and submits them. Dispatch being async is helpful, though.

Comment: Using a promise or await was my initial assumption as well, but unfortunately produces the same result. The route gets rejected as first, but second submission goes through.

Comment: Could you show me the `obtainToken`? It should return `promise`(may be fetching).

Comment: Please reference this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113023/triggering-a-route-only-after-dispatch-and-commit-completed-in-vuejs

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be in the `login` method.

```
login() {
      this.$store.dispatch('obtainToken', { email: this.email, password: this.password })
      this.$router.push('dashboard')
}
```

Will be running both calls simultaneously. Attempting to navigate the user before the result of the obtain token call.

```
login() {
      this.$store.dispatch('obtainToken', { email: this.email, password: this.password })
      .then(() =>
           this.$router.push('dashboard')
      )
}
```

Once the token exists, it can be fetched from state when navigating to the dashboard.